# How do I pass a class to a function and instantiate an object of that class in the function?

Tags: java, class

Something like this. The way the class is passed is probably correct but the object instantiation method does not work. Should I approach this differently?

```
private void init() {
    makeObject(ClassA.class);
    makeObject(ClassB.class);
    makeObject(ClassC.class);
}

private void makeObject(Class<?> myClass) {
    new myClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use reflection to create an instance from a `Class` object :

```
private void makeObject(Class<?> myClass) {
    Object o = myClass.newInstace();
}
```

Of course you probably want to return the created instance from your method, and you have to handle some checked exceptions that `newInstance` may throw.